# How to convert WAV stream to MP3 using Naudio?

Tags: c#, naudio

I've seen a sample in Naudio documentation that it converts the MP3 stream to WAV stream. My doubt is, does Naudio do it in reverse? That is, can it convert a WAV stream to MP3 stream? If yes, please explain how or help me with some references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NAudio does not come with an MP3 encoder or decoder - it simply gives you access to the codecs that are already installed on your system. Until Windows 8, Windows did not ship with an MP3 encoder, so your best option was to convert to WAV using something like [LAME.exe](http://lame.sourceforge.net/). I explain how you can do this on the fly towards the end of [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/501521/How-to-convert-between-most-audio-formats-in-NET).

In Windows 8, there is an MP3 encoder, which you access with the new `MediaFoundationEncoder.EncodeToMp3` function. This is currently pre-release for NAudio v1.7, but you can try it out by getting the [latest build from nuget](https://nuget.org/packages/NAudio/).

Comment: can we record mp3 in windows phone 8. . .

Comment: @ggsmartboy I don't have a wp8, but I have a feeling that it records in MP3 for you - the challenge is getting it as WAV.

Comment: @Mark Heath by default wp8 recording in the wav format that's y asked. Moreover if the file format is mp3 we can add id3tag's.

Comment: Any update on this? Has this been integrated in NAudio in the meanwhile?

Comment: yes, the mediafoundationencoder is in the latest NAudio 1.7.3